# Does anyone know the code for generating a barcode scanner in B4a

Tags: basic4android

I'm trying to create an android app using B4A which holds a Barcode or QR code, so my question is: does anyone know the code for generating Barcode or Qr scanner in B4A. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this http://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/abzxing-barcode-reader.7303/ It uses an external app (Zxing) to scan the barcode, which then returns the value of the barcode